# Typeorm cannot find postgres driver module error

Tags: javascript, typescript, server, typeorm

i I created a server with typeorm and am facing an error when trying to run it locally on a digital ocean vm. i get the following error when i run it. this server runs perfectly on my local machine but has some difficulty running on a server. i tried installing `pg` but kept on getting this error:

```bash
yarn run v1.22.21
$ nodemon dist/index.js
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../driver/postgres/PostgresDriver'
Require stack:
- /root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/schema-builder/RdbmsSchemaBuilder.js
- /root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/driver/sqlserver/SqlServerDriver.js
- /root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/migration/MigrationExecutor.js
- /root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js
- /root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/connection/ConnectionManager.js
- /root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/globals.js
- /root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/index.js
- /root/lumos/server/dist/index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/schema-builder/RdbmsSchemaBuilder.js:11:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/schema-builder/RdbmsSchemaBuilder.js',
    '/root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/driver/sqlserver/SqlServerDriver.js',
    '/root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/migration/MigrationExecutor.js',
    '/root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js',
    '/root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/connection/ConnectionManager.js',
    '/root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/globals.js',
    '/root/lumos/server/node_modules/typeorm/index.js',
    '/root/lumos/server/dist/index.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.13.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

my package.json –

```json
{
    "name": "server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "gen-env": "gen-env-types .env -o src/env.d.ts -e .",
        "build": "tsc",
        "watch": "tsc -w",
        "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js",
        "start": "node dist/index.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "dependencies": {
        "@apollo/server": "^4.4.0",
        "apollo-server-express": "2.25.0",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1040.0",
        "axios": "^1.3.4",
        "connect-redis": "^6.0.0",
        "cookie-encrypter": "^1.0.1",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv-safe": "^8.2.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-session": "^1.17.2",
        "google-drive": "^0.0.8",
        "graphql": "^15.6.1",
        "graphql-type-json": "^0.3.2",
        "ioredis": "^4.27.11",
        "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
        "multer-s3": "^2.10.0",
        "passport-google-oauth": "^2.0.0",
        "passport-google-oauth2": "^0.2.0",
        "pg": "^8.11.3",
        "punycode": "^2.3.1",
        "querystring": "^0.2.1",
        "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
        "typeorm": "^0.2.38"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/connect-redis": "^0.0.17",
        "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
        "@types/express-session": "^1.17.4",
        "@types/graphql-type-json": "^0.3.2",
        "@types/ioredis": "^4.27.6",
        "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
        "@types/multer-s3": "^2.7.11",
        "@types/node": "^16.11.8",
        "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
        "@types/passport": "^1.0.12",
        "@types/passport-google-oauth": "^1.0.42",
        "@types/passport-google-oauth2": "^0.1.5",
        "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
        "argon2": "^0.28.2",
        "gen-env-types": "^1.3.0",
        "nodemailer": "^6.6.5",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
        "passport": "^0.6.0",
        "typescript": "^4.5.2",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

my machine

```
Linux ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-amd-sfo3-01 6.5.0-9-generic #9-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Oct  7 01:35:40 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```